# How to write integration test for an endpoint that uses Braintree with static method calls

Tags: php, integration-testing, braintree, mockery

I am using the [Braintree PHP](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php) Client which relies heavily on static methods.
All my endpoints in this project are covered with integration tests
Something like:

```
Storage::shouldReceive('put')->once()->andReturn(true);

$this->post('/api/payment');
```

As you can see I'm also using Mockery in order to create mocks. However since the Braintree library is heavily relying on static methods, I'm not able to create methods, thus not able to test these endpoints.

Here's an example of a code written using the Braintree PHP Client:

```
$result = Braintree\Transaction::sale([
    'amount' => '1000.00',
    'paymentMethodNonce' => 'nonceFromTheClient',
    'options' => [ 'submitForSettlement' => true ]
]);
```

What options do I have here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35321206/766570) will only work if you got `mockery 1.*` installed.. earlier versions won't do static method mocking. The below code works:

```
    $brainTreeMock = Mockery::mock('alias:Braintree_Transaction');

    $transaction = (object)[ 'id' => str_random(5) ];
    $brainTreeMock->shouldReceive('sale')->andReturn((object)[
        'success'     => true,
        'transaction' => $transaction
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Mocking one of the components during **integration** tests should be done with great care, as it defeats the purpose.

I believe Braintree provides a [sanbox](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/php#testing-in-sandbox) for integration testing, so there is no need to mock it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [alias mock](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/public_static_properties.html) to mock public static method calls. You would use it like this:

```
$classMock = Mockery::mock('alias:NamespaceToClass\ClassName');
$classMock->shouldReceive('someMethod')->once()->andReturn('Something');
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually I would advocate mocking the responses from an API instead of making calls to it when running integration tests.
However, I contacted Braintree and they said (at time of writing) that it's ok to run the tests vs the sandbox as long as you don't exceed 25 concurrent requests per second.